# select query to get result by merging two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like below :

```
Id   Price1  Price2
3     30       20
3     40       20
3     50       20
```

I want to write a query to get a below result :

Desired Ouput :

```
RowNo  Id Price
1       3  20
2       3  30
3       3  40
4       3  50
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Cross apply` to unpivot the data and generate row number

```
SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY price) AS Rowno,*
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Id,
                        Price
        FROM   (VALUES (3,30,20),
                       (3,40,20),
                       (3,50,20) ) tc ( Id, Price1, Price2)
               CROSS apply (VALUES (Price1),
                                   (Price2)) Cs (Price)) A
```

**Result :**

```
╔═══════╦════╦═══════╗
║ Rowno ║ Id ║ Price ║
╠═══════╬════╬═══════╣
║     1 ║  3 ║    20 ║
║     2 ║  3 ║    30 ║
║     3 ║  3 ║    40 ║
║     4 ║  3 ║    50 ║
╚═══════╩════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `union` to combine the rows (so duplicates are removed).  And then `row_number()` to calculate `rownum`:

```
select row_number() over (order by price) as rownum, id, price
from ((select id, price1 as price from t) union
      (select id, price2 from t
     ) t
order by price;
```